# Initialize data member depends on condition inside constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Fraction {

    int numerator;
    int denominator;

public:

    Fraction(int a, int b) {

       if (a > 0 && b > 0) {
            numerator = a;
            denominator = b;
       }
       else {
           Fraction();
       }
   }

   Fraction() {
       numerator = 0;
       denominator = 0;
   }

   void display() const {
       if (numerator == 0 && denominator == 0) {
           cout << "data member is 0" << endl;
       }
       else {
           cout << "data member is not 0" << endl;
       }
   }
};

int main(void) {

   Fraction c(-5,15);
   c.display();

   return 0;
}
```

What I expect is to print out "data member is 0 " because I passed -5 when create object, which does not match the condition inside Fraction(int a, int b).
However, it print out "data member is not 0". So I tried to print out each data member and it printed out the address of data member like -8776877. 
please help me out

Comment: @DimChtz But it doesn't have to: https://wandbox.org/permlink/CItojqIazC0gqiKS The members are left in an uninitialized state

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually reassigning the values of numerator and denominator.

In your else statement, you just call Fraction(). This just calls the constructor for the Fraction class and doesn't do anything with it. So at the very end of code, numerator and denominator still haven't been assigned to 0.

What you should do in the else statement is :

```
else {
    numerator = 0;
    denominator = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What I want to do is to call another constructor that initialize each value. is it wrong?

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted when it is right.  Have an up vote

Comment: You can call another constructor from one in c++11, however, it wouldn't be a good idea for this use case. It would be easier to simply reassign the values as I've stated

Answer (score 1):

You can default-initialize the data members in the class declaration and rely upon a compiler-generated default constructor,

```
class Fraction {
  public:
    Fraction() = default;
    Fraction(int a, int b);

  private:
    int numerator = 0;
    int denominator = 0;
};
```

This way, you don't have to call the default constructor at all from the user defined one:

```
Fraction::Fraction(int a, int b) {
    if (a > 0 && b > 0) {
        numerator = a;
        denominator = b;
    }
}
```

There are other options, but the in-class initializers with meaningful default values is the one suggested by the [CoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c45-dont-define-a-default-constructor-that-only-initializes-data-members-use-in-class-member-initializers-instead).